# Django ManyToManyField and values from other class

Tags: django, manytomanyfield

I have a lot of standard services with different prices in different ServicePlaces.

My models.py:

```
class Service(models.Model):
    service = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)

class ServicePlace(models.Model):
    place = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    #what services are provided in this ServicePlace:
    service = models.ManyToManyField('Service')

class Price(models.Model):
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    service = models.ForeignKey("Service")
    place = models.ForeignKey("Place")
```

How I can get all services with prices for the ServicePlace X ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the stupid question. The answer is in the Django [manual](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through_fields).

Answer (score 0):

You have a direct relationship from ServicePlace to Service, so you can just follow that:

```
services = service_place_x.service.all()
```

(Note your `service` field is misnamed, because it refers to *multiple* objects, so it should probably be called `services`.)

From there, you can access the price directly on each service:

```
for service in services:
   price = service.price
```

This incurs an extra db hit on each iteration though, so you probably want to use `select_related` on the original query:

```
services = service_place_x.service.all().select_related('price')
```

Comment: This code does't work 

   `for service in services: price = service.price`

(AttributeError: 'Service' object has no attribute 'price'):